# Xcode 11 beta 4: SwiftUI Preview & Build Phase agvtool incompatible?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I have a project with a variety of views running. All of them can be previewed.

When adding `xcrun agvtool next-version -all` as run script build phase, the preview breaks.

This is really strange - can this be workaround somehow?

Comment: Beta 5 was just released.

Comment: jepp, but unfortunately not macOS beta 5 yet...

Comment: Finally released. 

Answer (score 4):

A bit late to the party but I just had the same problem,

Xcode exposes an ENABLE_PREVIEWS variable which is set to YES when building for live previews. In other cases it is NO

```
if [ $ENABLE_PREVIEWS = NO ]; then
   xcrun agvtool next-version -all
fi
```

Comment: Thanks! This resolved my SwiftFormat breaking previews